# How to write a column template to display and checked the checkbox conditionally where Columns are generating dynamically

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a requirement to generate the number of columns dynamically while loading the screen based on the value that comes from database. I could create the Kendo grid columns based on the input.

But these columns should display checkboxes and those checkboxes should be checked or unchecked conditionally. If we click on any of the checkboxes it should call the javascript method to execute some other logic in the page.

[DOJO Example for this issue](https://dojo.telerik.com/iViDIXat/8)

JSON Structure:

```
var books = [
        {"bookID": 87688, "bookName": "Book AAA",
            "pages": [
                {"id": 124, "pageNumber": 1,  "contentPeriodAlias": "b"},
                {"id": 103, "pageNumber": 1,  "contentPeriodAlias": "a"},
                {"id": 127, "pageNumber": 2,  "contentPeriodAlias": "a"},
                {"id": 101, "pageNumber": 2,  "contentPeriodAlias": "b"}
                
            ]
        },
        {"bookID": 87689, "bookName": "Book BBB",
            "pages": [
                {"id": 125, "pageNumber": 2,  "contentPeriodAlias": "a" },
                {"id": 126, "pageNumber": 2,  "contentPeriodAlias": "b" },
                {"id": 105, "pageNumber": 1,  "contentPeriodAlias": "b" },
                {"id": 104, "pageNumber": 1,  "contentPeriodAlias": "a" }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

Here pages are stored in the database, so these values are coming from the database.

```
var maxPages = 3;
var pageSides = ["a","b"];
```

Here it should create 6 dynamic columns like `1a,1b,2a,2b,3a,3b`. It is generating in the given dojo example.

After these columns created, the checkbox for `1a,1b,2a,2b` columns in 2 rows should be checked as this value already persisted in database and `3a,3b` column checkboxes should not be checked. Also, if click on any checkbox it should call a javascript method by passing bookID and column name like 1a or 3b to update the records.

I tried different approaches to achieve this, but due to the dynamic creation of columns not able to access the particular checkbox column name in the Kendo Grid column template.

Could someone please advice me any best approach to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, all your checkboxes have the same is. Use a class instead, or use kendo.guid() to generate ids, or use the data item's uid. For instance:

```
template: function(dataItem) { return  `<input type="checkbox" id="${dataItem.uid}_${rowNumber}_${alias}" />` }
```

Since your rows have a bookID, you can create unique and deterministic ids for the checkboxes this way:

```
return  `<input type="checkbox" id="${dataItem.bookID}_${rowNumber}_${alias}" />`
```

I'm not sure how your logic is exactly supposed to work, so I can't provide a full solution, but unique and deterministic ids may be your missing piece.

You can also dig in kendo's observables and how they keep track of unsaved changes. A grid row has a model with a dirty flag: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#dirty-boolean , which keeps track of whether the entire row has changes. To keep track of changed columns, you'll need to implement something along those lines: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/preserve-the-dirty-indicator-in-incell-editing-and-client-operations

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer, but I am looking for this solution  https://dojo.telerik.com/ujaqoNIp/17